# Imprimir datos de un json en un input html

Tags: javascript, html, json

Tengo problemas para mostrar el resultado de un Json, dentro de una etiqueta html: **input**, pero si me imprime en un: textarea y en una tabla pero no imprime dentro del **input**
esta es mi función js:

```
function consultar() {
    var ced = document.getElementById("cedu").value;
    var gen = document.getElementById("generico").value;
    var id = document.getElementById("idRepresentante").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'www/getPaso1_ConsultarIdentificacionPorGenerico.php',
        data: {cedu: ced, generico: gen, idRepresentante: id},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {   
            //Muestro datos en la tabla (SI MUESTRA DATOS)
            $.each(data, function () {
                $('#a1').text(data.cedula);
                $('#a2').text(data.cupo);
                $('#a3').text(data.entrada);
                $('#a4').text(data.plazo);
                $('#a5').text(data.cuota);
            });          
            //Muestro en un texarea (SI MUESTRA DATOS)
            $('#j1').text(data.datosSolicitud.txtPrimerApellido);
            //Muestro en un input (NO MUESTRA DATOS)
            $('#j2').text(data.datosSolicitud.txtPrimerApellido);           
        }
    }
    );
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea type="text" id="j1"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="j2">
```

Comment: Saludos. Le falto incluir el código; por lo menos un textarea, input, el JavaScript y (parte) del JSON; con ello se le puede orientar a su consulta.

Comment: ¿No sera porque en las lineas donde estas tratando de mostrar los datos estan fuera del each?

Comment: Para actualizar elementos de formulario se usa `$('#j2').val(valor);` y tú lo estás intentando con `text(valor)`

Answer (score 1):

revisa esto,

```js
 //JSON para imitar el procedimiento.
 data = {"cedula" : 123}
 //Para buscar por id se obtienen con # 
 $('#cedula').val(data.cedula);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cedula" required >
```